# Folders will not launch or open, desktop displays fine

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer

No folders will open on my computer. Neither right-click->open or double-click works. Windows explorer still runs fine, as my desktop is displaying, and I can restart the process. Restarting the explorer.exe process does not fix the problem. There is no error message at any time.

I created a new user account, and this account does not have the folder opening problem -- so is there a problem with my user profile? Has anyone seen this problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have either managed to loose the association between folders and Windows Explorer or more likely have some slight corruption of Windows Registry.

The fact that the other user doesn't have the problem confirms that.

There is no error because Windows does not see any action associated with folders. To fix, you will need to investigate which registry entries manage the "open" task for folders and reset the damaged account in line with the working one.

Alternatively, you could do a reset of Windows but you will loose your installed software if you do that.

Comment: Not sure how I fixed the problem, but playing around with the windows explorer settings within the registry was the solution.